# gyp ERR! stack Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install gridfs

using the command:
npm install gridfs --save

but I am getting the following error:

> U:\code\hes-plus-jobs\node_modules\mongodb-client-encryption>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "U:\bin\node-v14.16.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "U:\bin\node-v14.16.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
> gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
> gyp ERR! configure error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
> gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.onError (U:\bin\node-v14.16.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
> gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
> gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
> gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
> gyp ERR! command "U:\bin\node-v14.16.1-win-x64\node.exe" "U:\bin\node-v14.16.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
> gyp ERR! cwd U:\code\hes-plus-jobs\node_modules\mongodb-client-encryption
> gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.1
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
> gyp ERR! not ok
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! mongodb-client-encryption@1.2.4 install: `prebuild-install --tag-prefix node-v || node-gyp rebuild`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the mongodb-client-encryption@1.2.4 install script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sugumar.Venkatesan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-06-09T03_05_01_308Z-debug.log